# grid products gallery plugins wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, grid, gallery, lightbox

did anyone know Wordpress Plugins Grid Products Gallery with left-right image display for each item. for example like this URL http://mwa.eu/products/ ?

is there any wordpress plugins or template like that?

Answer (score 0):

It could be easily done by changing CSS on every second image element of the grid from float left to float right.
If you have some experience in CSS and HTML it's a 5 minutes work, assuming you have some basic layout.

Comment: hmmm, ok, but i'm using wordpress for this case, that's why i am searching the plugins like that. :D